# variable goes away from IntelliJ debug variable view

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am debugging a program with IntelliJ IDEA and seeing a very strange behavior. I am going line-by-line through the init() method below. In the variables view, at first it says `A_DIR = null` and `A_DATASET = null`. Once I pass the line where A_DIR is set, it highlights `A_DIR = 'my/dir'` in the view. So far all is as expected.

But once I pass the second line where A_DATASET is set (so that the debugger is now resting on the line `String abc = "xyz"`), `A_DATASET = myfile.csv` is highlighted as expected, but the line for `A_DIR` has gone away! It is no longer showing the value of the `A_DIR` variable in the debug view!

There is no reason for the variable to be unset now, but IntelliJ is deciding to hide it for some reason.

The variable is `A_DIR` is greyed out in the source code view because it is never used. Is this maybe the reason that it is hiding it?

```
public class MyClass {
    private static String A_DIR;
    private static String A_DATASET;

    public MyClass() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        try {
            propertyFinder = MyOtherClass.getPropertyFinder();
            A_DIR = propertyFinder.getTheDirectory();
            A_DATASET = propertyFinder.getTheDataSet();
            String abc = "xyz";
        }
         catch (IOException ieo) {
            log.error(ieo.getMessage(), ieo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Variables view shows a subset of variables which IntelliJ IDEA considers to be most relevant for the current context. If a variable disappears from the view, it does not mean that it has become unset, or anything else about the logic of your code; it's just IntelliJ trying to be context-sensitive.

If you want to see the value of the variable anyway, you can press the "New Watch" button and enter the variable name; then it will always be visible.